# Tensorflow Extended: Is it possible to use pytorch training loop in Tensorflow extended flow

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tfx, mlops

I have trained an image classification model using pytorch.
Now, I want to move it from research to production pipeline.
I am thinking of using TensorFlow extended. I have a very noob doubt that will I'll be able to use my PyTorch trained model in the TensorFlow extended pipeline(I can convert the trained model to ONNX and then to Tensorflow compatible format).
I don't want to rewrite and retrain the training part to TensorFlow as it'll be a great overhead.
Is it possible or Is there any better way to productionize the PyTorch trained models?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convert your PyTorch image classification model to Tensorflow format using ONNX, as long as you are using standard layers. I would recommend doing the conversion and then look at both model summaries to make sure they are relatively similar. Also, do some tests to make sure your converted model handles any particular edge cases you have. Once you have confirmed that the converted model works, save your model as a TF `SavedModel` format and then you should be able to use it in Tensorflow Extended (TFX).

For more info on the conversion process, see this tutorial: https://learnopencv.com/pytorch-to-tensorflow-model-conversion/

Answer (score 0):

You could considering using the [torchX](https://pytorch.org/torchx/latest/) library. I haven't use it yet, but it seems to make it easier to deploy models by creating and running model pipelines. I don't think it has the same data validation functionality that Tensorflow Extended has, but maybe that will be added in the future.

Comment: Some layers like LSTMs can't be converted, they don't have the same implementation in the 2 frameworks.